# Only run one part of a Drupal behaviour once per page load?

Tags: javascript

I have a Drupal behaviour that's working fine. This is to say that it is re-run when new content is pulled into the page with AJAX.

However I would like one part of this behaviour to only run when its first called, and then to not be called again (until the page is reloaded).

So in the code below logging A should run every time the behaviour is called, as is the standard Drupal way. Logging B should run when the behaviour is first called, but then not again even if the behaviour is re-run.

```
Drupal.module.custom = function () {

  console.log('A');

  console.log('B');

};
```

Comment: for the console.log('B') you can use jQuery.once function.

Comment: But wont that be rerun the element Im applying once too is reloaded? I dont want this default behaviour.

Comment: Nope it will not reload, jQuery.once function will be loaded only on page load. Excellent article written on this http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-7-prevent-duplicating-javascript-behaviors